# If Size == 0 is not working

Tags: apex

I am having issues on these part, wherein it should work because if size is 0 or there is no task on that account it should set that field to false already.

```
    for(Id acctId : forWhatID){
            if(TaskCompletedMap.containsKey(acctId){
                if(accountIdToListDepMap.containsKey(acctId)){
                    for(Dependent__c covMem : accountIdToListDepMap.get(acctId)){
                        if(cIdToListDepMap.containsKey(covMem.Cover__c)){
                            for(Dependent__c depMem2 : cIdToListDepMap.get(covMem.Cover__c)){
                                accountsToUpdate.put(depMem2.Account__c, new Account(Id=depMem2.Account__c, Good__c=true, Comply__c=true)); 
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                } 
            }
            else{           
                if(TaskCompletedMap..get(acctId).size() == 0{
                if(accountIdToListDepMap.containsKey(acctId)){
                    for(Dependent__c covMem : accountIdToListDepMap.get(acctId)){
                        if(cIdToListDepMap.containsKey(covMem.Cover__c)){
                            for(Dependent__c depMem2 : cIdToListDepMap.get(covMem.Cover__c)){
                                accountsToUpdate.put(depMem2.Account__c, new Account(Id=depMem2.Account__c, Good__c=false, Comply__c=false)); 
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                } 
            }
```

Comment: Hi Cloud. There are no fewer than three `size() == 0` comparisons in this large block of code. Please [edit] your question to give a clearer description of what you're doing and how its behavior needs to change, and cut the code down to a clear, minimal example.

Comment: HI David, what I want to achieve in here is what if, there is no task on the related list of the account, it should set the field on the account as false.. not sure the problem

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question. I see a lot of code in your post that doesn't appear to be connected to that objective at all. Please make sure you are showing us only what is relevant to this problem.

Comment: How does this line `if(TaskCompletedMap..get(acctId).size() == 0{` compile? It looks like youre missing a `)` before the `{`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, there are many compilation errors in the code that you have mentioned in the question, so you will have to fix that.

Coming to the issue you are facing, your `else` condition will never run if your `map` contains all the `account ids` because you are just checking for `containsKey` and not `size>0`.

If you want to update account (set value as false) even when there are no completed tasks associated with it, then you can go for any of the two options

- `TaskCompletedMap` map only contains those `account ids` where they have atleast one completed tasks, then, you can have single check of `containsKey` in `if`and `else` would handle all the other accounts without tasks (without need for checking `size==0`).
- `TaskCompletedMap` map has all the account records i.e. with zero tasks including, then, in addition to `containsKey` check (move this to an outer `if`), you will have to check for  `TaskCompletedMap.get(acctId).size() >0` and in `else` would handle all the other accounts without tasks (without need for checking `size==0`).

Comment: how this will be? TaskCompletedMap map has all the account records i.e. with zero tasks including, then, in addition to containsKey check (move this to an outer if), you will have to check for TaskCompletedMap.get(acctId).size() >0 and in else would handle all the other accounts without tasks (without need for checking size==0).

Comment: sorry I have tried that but it seems it doesn't still work

Comment: or maybe I miss something

Comment: @Cloud Can you post your updated code, so that I can check what you might be missing.

Comment: Hi Vijay, already worked, i just modified the soql query thank you so much!

Comment: @Cloud That's great !!